# My pygame crashes randomly on start, collision, or just when it feels like

Tags: python

I'm coding a 'catch' game where a character is chased by a single enemy, and has to chase two other characters to earn points. My code works fine most of the time, but will crash randomly on startup, when the character chasing collides with enemies or with other characters, or just in the middle of gameplay. I've been going over the problem with my teacher for the last two weeks, but neither of us can figure out what is going wrong. He told me to hand it in as is, but I really do want to know how I can make it work. If anyone has any insight into how I can fix the problem, or what might be the issue, I'd be much obliged.

```
#Animation Programming Assignment: Cat and Mouse

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

import random

pygame.mixer.pre_init(frequency=22050, size=-16, channels=1, buffer=256)
pygame.init()

#Screen Junk
pygame.init()
width = 656
height = 498
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
black = (0, 0, 0)


#All the text set up stuff
pygame.display.set_caption("Cat and Mouse")


#Title
titleObj = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 22)

titleTxt = "Cat and Mouse"


#Start
startObj = pygame.font.Font("freesansbold.ttf", 18)

startTxt = "Press 'P' to Start!"


#Score
scoreObj = pygame.font.Font( "freesansbold.ttf" , 22)

score = 0
scoreTxt = "Score: " + str(score)


#Lives
livesObj = pygame.font.Font( "freesansbold.ttf" , 22)

lives = 3
livesTxt = "Lives: " + str(lives)


#Music
audioObj = pygame.font.Font( "freesansbold.ttf" , 12)

audioTxt = "Music by Visager"


#End
endObj = pygame.font.Font( "freesansbold.ttf" , 22)

endTxt = "Press 'P' to play again!"


#Images
bakImg = pygame.image.load("bkgnd.png").convert()
catImg = pygame.image.load("catFace.png").convert_alpha()
dogImg = pygame.image.load("dogFace.png").convert_alpha()
mosImg = pygame.image.load("mouse.png").convert_alpha()
yrnImg = pygame.image.load("yarn.png").convert_alpha()
scrImg = scoreObj.render(scoreTxt, True, black)
livImg = livesObj.render(livesTxt, True, black)
audImg = audioObj.render(audioTxt, True, black)
ttlImg = titleObj.render(titleTxt, True, black)
staImg = startObj.render(startTxt, True, black)
endImg = endObj.render(endTxt, True, black)


#Image Widths/Heights
cWid = catImg.get_width()
cHgt = catImg.get_height()

dWid = dogImg.get_width()
dHgt = dogImg.get_height()

mWid = mosImg.get_width()
mHgt = mosImg.get_height()

yWid = yrnImg.get_width()
yHgt = yrnImg.get_height()

sWid = scrImg.get_width()
sHgt = scrImg.get_height()

lWid = livImg.get_width()
lHgt = livImg.get_height()

aWid = audImg.get_width()
aHgt = audImg.get_height()

tWid = ttlImg.get_width()
tHgt = ttlImg.get_height()

stWid = staImg.get_width()
stHgt = staImg.get_height()

eWid = endImg.get_width()
eHgt = endImg.get_height()


#Image X/Y
catX = (width//2) - (cWid/2)
catY = height//2 - cHgt//2

dogX = random.randint(1, width - dWid)
dogY = random.randint(1, height - dHgt)

while dogX < catX + cWid and dogX + dWid > catX and dogY < catY + cHgt and dogY + dHgt > catY:
    dogX = random.randint(1, width - dWid)
    dogY = random.randint(1, height - dHgt)

mosX = width//2
mosY = width//2

while mosX < catX + cWid and mosX + mWid > catX and mosY < catY + cHgt and mosY + mHgt > catY:
    mosX = random.randint(1, width - mWid)
    mosY = random.randint(1, height - mHgt)

yrnX = random.randint(1, width - yWid)
yrnY = random.randint(1, height - yHgt)

while yrnX < catX + cWid and yrnX + yWid > catX and yrnY < catY + cHgt and yrnY + yHgt > catY:
    yrnX = random.randint(1, width - (yWid-10))
    yrnY = random.randint(1, height - (yHgt-10))

scrX = width//2 - sWid//2
scrY = 20

livX = width//2 - lWid//2
livY = 40

audX = (width - aWid) - 10
audY = (height - aHgt) - 10

ttlX = (width//2) - (tWid//2)
ttlY = 60

staX = (width//2) - (stWid//2)
staY = 90


#Speeds
catXSpd = 0
catYSpd = 0

dogXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)
dogYSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

while dogXSpd == 0:
    dogXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

while dogYSpd == 0:
    dogXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

mosXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)
mosYSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

while mosXSpd == 0:
    mosXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

while mosYSpd == 0:
    mosXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

yrnXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)
yrnYSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

while yrnXSpd == 0:
    yrnXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

while yrnYSpd == 0:
    yrnXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)


#Audio Things
pygame.mixer.music.load('windyBluffs.mp3')
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1, 0.0)

mosSnd = pygame.mixer.Sound('mosSound.ogg')
dogSnd = pygame.mixer.Sound('dogSound.ogg')
catSnd = pygame.mixer.Sound('catSound.ogg')

#Drawing permanent junk
screen.blit(bakImg, (0, 0))
screen.blit(audImg, (audX, audY))


#Start Screen
start = True
while start:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_p:
                start = False

        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if event.key == K_p:
                running = True

    screen.blit(bakImg, (0, 0))
    screen.blit(ttlImg, (ttlX, ttlY))
    screen.blit(staImg, (staX, staY))

    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.delay(5)

#Main Game
running = True
while running:
    playing = True
    while playing:
        #Exit
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            #Keyboard Junk
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                    catXSpd = 3
                if event.key == K_LEFT:
                    catXSpd = -3
                if event.key == K_UP:
                    catYSpd = -3
                if event.key == K_DOWN:
                    catYSpd = 3

            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_RIGHT or event.key == K_LEFT:
                    catXSpd = 0
                if event.key == K_UP or event.key == K_DOWN:
                    catYSpd = 0

        screen.blit(scrImg, (scrX, scrY))
        screen.blit(livImg, (livX, livY))

        dogX += dogXSpd
        dogY += dogYSpd

        mosX += mosXSpd
        mosY += mosYSpd

        yrnX += yrnXSpd
        yrnY += yrnYSpd

        if dogX >= width - dWid or dogX <= 0:
            dogXSpd *= -1

        if dogY >= height - dHgt or dogY <= 0:
            dogYSpd *= -1


        if mosX >= width - cWid or mosX <= 0:
            mosXSpd *= -1

        if mosY >= height - mHgt or mosY <= 0:
            mosYSpd *= -1


        if yrnX >= width - cWid or yrnX <= 0:
            yrnXSpd *= -1

        if yrnY >= height - yHgt or yrnY <= 0:
            yrnYSpd *= -1

        catX += catXSpd
        catY += catYSpd

        if catX >=  width - cWid:
            cXSpd = 0
            catX = width - cWid
        elif catX <= 0:
            cXSpd = 0
            catX = 0

        if catY >=  height - cHgt:
            cYSpd = 0
            catY = height - cHgt
        elif catY <= 0:
            cYSpd = 0
            catY = 0


        #Score
        if mosX < catX + cWid and mosX + mWid > catX and mosY < catY + cHgt and mosY + mHgt > catY:
            pygame.init()
            mosSnd.play()
            score = score + 2
            scoreTxt = "Score: " + str(score)
            scrImg = scoreObj.render(scoreTxt, True, black)
            sWid = scrImg.get_width()
            sHgt = scrImg.get_height()
            scrX = width//2 - sWid//2
            scrY = 20

            catX = random.randint(1, (width-cWid))
            catY = random.randint(1, (height-cHgt))

            while mosX < catX + cWid and mosX + mWid > catX and mosY < catY + cHgt and mosY + mHgt > catY:
                mosX = random.randint(1, width - mWid)
                mosY = random.randint(1, height - mHgt)

            mosXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)
            mosYSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

            while mosXSpd == 0:
                mosXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

            while mosYSpd == 0:
                mosXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

        if yrnX < catX + cWid and yrnX + yWid > catX and yrnY < catY + cHgt and yrnY + yHgt > catY:
            catSnd.play()
            score = score + 1
            scoreTxt = "Score: " + str(score)
            scrImg = scoreObj.render(scoreTxt, True, black)
            sWid = scrImg.get_width()
            sHgt = scrImg.get_height()
            scrX = width//2 - sWid//2
            scrY = 20

            yrnX = random.randint(1, (width-mWid))
            yrnY = random.randint(1, (height-mHgt))

            while yrnX < catX + cWid and yrnX + yWid > catX and yrnY < catY + cHgt and yrnY + yHgt > catY:
                yrnX = random.randint(1, width - yWid)
                yrnY = random.randint(1, height - yHgt)

            yrnXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)
            yrnYSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

            while yrnXSpd == 0:
                yrnXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

            while yrnYSpd == 0:
                yrnXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

        #Lives
        if dogX < catX + cWid and dogX + dWid > catX and dogY < catY + cHgt and dogY + dHgt > catY:
            dogSnd.play()
            lives = lives - 1
            livesTxt = "Lives: " + str(lives)
            livImg = livesObj.render(livesTxt, True, black)
            lWid = livImg.get_width()
            lHgt = livImg.get_height()
            livX = width//2 - lWid//2
            livY = 40

            if lives == 0:
                playing = False


            dogX = random.randint(1, (width-dWid))
            dogY = random.randint(1, (height-dHgt))
            dogXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)
            dogYSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

            while dogX < catX + cWid and dogX + dWid > catX and dogY < catY + cHgt and dogY + dHgt > catY:
                dogX = random.randint(1, width - dWid)
                dogY = random.randint(1, height - dHgt)

            while dogXSpd == 0:
                dogXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

            while dogYSpd == 0:
                dogXSpd = random.randint(-2, 2)

        screen.blit(bakImg, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(mosImg, (mosX, mosY))
        screen.blit(yrnImg, (yrnX, yrnY))
        screen.blit(catImg, (catX, catY))
        screen.blit(dogImg, (dogX, dogY))
        screen.blit(scrImg, (scrX, scrY))
        screen.blit(livImg, (livX, livY))
        screen.blit(audImg, (audX, audY))

        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(5)


    #End Screen
    end = True
    while end:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_p:
                    playing = True
                    start = False

                    lives = 3
                    livesTxt = "Lives: " + str(lives)
                    livImg = livesObj.render(livesTxt, True, black)
                    lWid = livImg.get_width()
                    lHgt = livImg.get_height()
                    livX = width//2 - lWid//2
                    livY = 40

                    score = 0
                    scoreTxt = "Score: " + str(score)
                    scrImg = scoreObj.render(scoreTxt, True, black)
                    sWid = scrImg.get_width()
                    sHgt = scrImg.get_height()
                    scrX = width//2 - sWid//2
                    scrY = 20


            if event.type == KEYUP:
                if event.key == K_p:
                    end = False
                    start = False

                    catX = (width//2) - (cWid/2)
                    catY = 520

                    catXSpd = 0
                    catYSpd = 0
                    screen.blit(catImg, (catX, catY))

        screen.blit(bakImg, (0, 0))
        screen.blit(endImg, ((width//2) - (eWid//2) , (height//2) - (eHgt//2)))

        pygame.display.update()
        pygame.time.delay(5)
```

Comment: The real problem is that you don't have functions in your code

Comment: One thing you might try is getting it to fail in a predictable manner.  Because of letting `random()` be non-deterministic (which is proper for the game), this will be hard.  Instead, provide a constant seed while debugging to random (`random.seed(1)`) at initialization and then try to find a sequence of game moves which results in the problem.  Once you have that, then maybe you can add some `print` to narrow the cause.

Comment: When I run the program it says I somehow no longer have pygame downloaded, so I feel as though this may be a much bigger issue on my end. I am currently literally looking at the pygame folder in Python32, running the game, and then getting an import error. Thank you so much for the help anyway.